# exporting to a pst file with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to export entire outlook accounts to a pst file using a powershell command. I am doing this in the exchange server so I do have the `new-mailboxexportrequest` option. My issue is when ever I try exporting from mailboxes it says the operation couldn't be performed because 'example.user' couldn't be found even though when using get-mailbox command I can see the person that I want the data exported from listed in powershell.

The exported command i'm trying to do is:

```
new-mailboxexportrequest -mailbox example.user -filepath \\example\exported_to_pst\example.pst
```

Just comes up as it cannot find `example.user` where `example.user` is the mailbox.

Please help me with this issue. It is driving me crazy!

Comment: Have your tried piping the results to that cmdlet? `Get-Mailbox example.user | New-MailBoxExportRequest -FilePath .......`?

Comment: oh whoops, just saw this comment. dunno why people post possible solutions in comments, but ignore mine if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can't remember if this works and I can't test these days, but what about piping your `Get-Mailbox` result to the export command?

```
Get-mailbox $user | new-mailboxexportrequest -FilePath "\\path...."
```

You might want to put your path in quotes too.

Also, for future reference, it helps if you supply the actual error. "Can't find user" can be lots of things...